# Tomcat 8 invalidates sessions behind apache server + SSL

Tags: apache, tomcat, ssl

I have an application (WAR) which uses basic authentication, it was working properly with tomcat 8 + SSL.

I moved to a new server where I have an apache server handling SSL , and a tomcat 8

what seems weird, the app keeps asking for authentication again! , using chrome developer tools, I found that jsessionid sent in request is not present in tomcat, that's why tomcat asks for authentication and sends a new jsessionid.

[image: Request - response]

Can someone tell me why sessions are destroyed on tomcat behind an apache ?

Comment: Please quote your relevant Apache config, especially the way you forward requests to Tomcat.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a reverse proxy server, you have to adjusts the Path string in Set-Cookie headers, in the Apache config file, for example:

```
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath  "/"  "/mirror/foo/"
```

When you mapped mysite.com to mysite.com/mirror/foo

Comment: A question is not normally an answer, and this doesn't appear to be any exception.